# What is the difference between Smart Data and Data tabs in JDeveloper debugger?

Tags: jdeveloper

I want to know the difference between the two tabs called `Data` and `Smart Data` tabs inside the debugger view of Jdeveloper ? When I tried to debug, I am seeing same data in both tabs .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Debugger window's Data tab shows all variables that are currently in scope and this can be potentially overwhelming if there are a lot of variables.  One solution to this is to set up "Watches" on variables you pick so you can focus on just the variables you're interested in, these appear in the Watches tab.  This is okay but requires some leg work on your part as you need to configure all the watches and becomes a bit of debugging pain in the butt.  Smart data works differently in that it assumes that you'll be interested in variables +/- X lines of where the current debugger line is instead, and it will automatically show and hide the variables in the Smart Data tab as you debug down the code lines based on this sliding window of +/- lines.

It is configured via Preferences -> Debugger -> Smart Data -> Number of Lines to Analyze.